# Wordpress 3.8.2 Appends ?ver=3.8.2 to filenames

Tags: wordpress, plugins, http-status-code-404

I'm working on a WordPress site and suddenly all our plugins are malfunctioning. Inspect Elements shows the following:

```
    GET http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/css/qtip.css?ver=3.8.2 404 (Not Found) (index):295
    GET http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/js/dev/word-and-character-counter.js?ver=3.8.2 404 (Not Found) (index):299
    GET http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/css/ninja-forms-display.css?ver=3.8.2 404 (Not Found) (index):294
    GET http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/css/jquery.rating.css?ver=3.8.2 404 (Not Found) (index):296
    GET http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/js/min/ninja-forms-display.min.js?ver=3.8.2 404 (Not Found)
```

These files are all set to 755 and do exist on our server. Can anyone help us figure out why ?ver=3.8.2 is appended and how to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's added by WordPress as a way of versioning the scripts.  It's intended to be used as a cache buster if you update a stylesheet/script file but don't change the name.  You can tell WordPress to not do this by filtering it out.  Add this to functions.php or a plugin.

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'remove_versions_from_scripts_and_stylesheets', 999 );
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'remove_versions_from_scripts_and_stylesheets', 999 );

function remove_versions_from_scripts_and_stylesheets( $src ) {
    if ( strstr( $src, 'ver=' ) ) {
        $src = remove_query_arg( 'ver', $src );
    }
    return $src;
}
```

Keep in mind this is just going to remove the version at the end, there may be a bigger issue.  If those files *do* exist on the server, the version thing wouldn't actually prevent them from loading.

Comment: Thanks! This isn't what I needed in the end (had a permissions issue when I changed hosting providers), but it helped me remove the variable for something else I was working on. Appreciated!